# How to pass 2 parameters separately to the EventEmitter to pass them to function in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function that takes 2 parameters

`students.component.ts`

```
write(name : string, age : number) : void {
      ...
}
```

`students.component.html`

```html
<app-student [student]="student" (write)="write(**?**)"></app-student>
```

how can I pass 2 variables from a child component?

`student.component.ts`

```
@Output() write = new EventEmitter();

writeStudentInfo(name : string, age : number) {
    this.write.emit(**?**);
}
```

Comment: Emit a _container_? Object, array, ...

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you'd either want two emitters, or change your code to be

```js
@Output() write = new EventEmitter();

writeStudentInfo(name : string, age : number) {
    this.write.emit({ name, age });
}
```

and then your host component listener could be

```js
onStudentInfo({name, age}) {
  // Do your thing here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@JSmart523 already answered correctly.

Just for your codes, see below,

`students.component.ts`

```
write(name : string, age : number) : void {
  console.log(name, age);
}
```

`students.component.html`

```html
<app-student [student]="student" (write)="write($event.name, $event.age)"></app-student>
```

`student.component.ts`

```
@Output() write = new EventEmitter();

writeStudentInfo(name : string, age : number) {
    this.write.emit({ name, age });
}
```